# Checkout agreements data-bind is not working

Tags: magento2

Checkout agreements data-bind to HTML is not working after upgrade to Magento version 2.2.8

```
<label data-bind="attr: {'for': 'agreement_custom_' + agreementId}">
      <input type="button" class="action action-show 3"
            data-bind="click: function(data, event) { return $parent.showContent(data, event) }">
            <span data-bind="html: checkboxText"></span>
      </input>
</label>
```

On frontend showing HTML everything seems okay with js

Answer (score 0):

The data for the agreements is provided by a configprovider in the class Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\AgreementsConfigProvider. On line 79 you can see the checkboxText gets escaped:

`'checkboxText' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($agreement->getCheckboxText()),`

You could write a preference for this class to prevent this behaviour as described in: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

The change was introduced a security fix. The html-binding in knockout does not make any sense and is misleading though.

Please check this issue for more information: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22350